# Are any well-known open-source projects helmed by women?

Tags: community

It appears most open source projects are headed by men; [this list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life) lists 29 men in charge of open source projects.  Considering the famous contributions in the history of computer science and software engineering by people like Ada Lovelace, Grace Hopper, Margaret Hamilton, and countless others, that seems a little unlikely or disappointing.  Are there any well-known open source projects where a woman is in charge?

Comment: I can certainly think of free-software projects headed by women whose project authority is widely recognised: [Julia Lawall](https://pages.lip6.fr/Julia.Lawall/) at [Coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) comes quickly to mind.  Given that it is *possible* (I say no more than that) that women tend to suffer less from the personality flaw that insists on formal coronation as BDFL, are you open to free-software projects helmed by women?  Or are you specifically after ones who've insisted on the hat?

Comment: @MadHatter I'm interested in both.  Edited question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks.  I think it's an interesting question, and hope it doesn't get closed.

Comment: Focusing on the "BDFL" label detracts from this question. The title is better now but you're still focusing on that label. Also the phrasing "cisgender males" is too obscure. Say it plain: Most projects seem to be headed by men; are there any prominent women open-source project leaders?

Comment: @Brandin Fair point.  Edited, maybe clearer now.

Comment: A BDFL is generally one who starts and keeps control of a project, but how many women have taken over an existing project? or how many have started a project and moved on leaving someone else running it. Then how many are major contributors to projects? Does a project have to be well known?

Comment: @sambler Those are all valid questions but I chose to focus an a single question in a single post.

Answer (score 5):

The [Coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) project (see also on [github](https://github.com/coccinelle/coccinelle))  was started by [Julia Lawall](https://pages.lip6.fr/Julia.Lawall/), and she's still one of the [core developers](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/people.php).  She's also considered authoritative on what it can and can't do; see eg this from [LWN's coverage](https://lwn.net/SubscriberLink/743265/d734556f570dd148/) of the linux kernel community's response to the Meltdown and Spectre vulnerabilities:

> Some developers have suggested using Coccinelle, but Julia Lawall, the creator of Coccinelle, has [concluded](https://lwn.net/Articles/743287/) that the task is too complex for that tool.